# log-out is not working in php for a login System

Tags: php

i am implementing a log-in system, i am sure a lot of you know what it is, i use sessions to store the user's ID, and check it if he access a page that needs the user to be logged in.
But my problem is when the user clicks the log-out anchor, nothing happens i still can access the other pages as long as the current page is open.
here is the code is use:

```
<?
unset($_SESSION["ID"]);
session_destroy();
header('location: ../Home/index.php');
?>
```

so anyone can help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do a `session_start()` before `session_destroy()`.

If you don't, PHP has no idea which session you're trying to destroy.

Comment: Otherwise PHP won't recognize the "ID" session variable.

Comment: thanks, that was the problem, really tired, i didn't see that. i did it every time i need the variable, but when destroying no. thanks again.

Comment: @abdelkrimnet: We all have days like that.

Answer (score 2):

> But my problem is when the user clicks
>   the log-out anchor, nothing happens

**A lot of things happens !**

1. Are you trying to go back with the previous button and then accessing to the login page which log you in back ?
2. Are you page really checking for a session when a user try to display ?
3. Are you sure you are NOT displaying a cached version of your page ?
4. Did you check PHP sessions files are well deleted ? (maybe permission problems can occurs)
5. Check the location header syntax, RFC2616 14.30 says:

> The Location response-header field is
>   used to redirect the recipient to a
>   location other than the Request-URI
>   for completion of the request or
>   identification of a new resource. For
>   201 (Created) responses, the Location
>   is that of the new resource which was
>   created by the request. For 3xx
>   responses, the location SHOULD
>   indicate the server's preferred URI
>   for automatic redirection to the
>   resource. The field value consists of
>   a single absolute URI.
>
> ```
>    Location       = "Location" ":" absoluteURI
> ```

Try:

`var_dump($_SESSION);`

On each of your page, to see what, really happens.

Answer (score 2):

[HTTP/1.1 requires absolute URI as an argument to `Location`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30). So it should be:

```
header('Location: http://example.com/home');
exit();     # just to be sure
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely you also have to delete the session cookie:

```
unset($_SESSION["ID"]);
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
}
session_destroy();
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

On Logout page it should be like below

```
<?php
    session_start()
    unset($_SESSION["ID"]);
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: http://example.com/home');
?>
```

And on other pages that you want to restrict without a login user. You need to write following code on each page:

```
<?php
    session_start()
    if(!isset($_SESSION["ID"]) || empty($_SESSION["ID"])) {
        // redirect to login page
        header('Location: http://example.com/login');
    }
?>
```